# Microsoft Flow Error: "You are not authorized to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account"

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow, send-email

Using `Microsoft flow` I am trying to send an email Notification on behalf of an Administrator's account.

Unfortunately, my attempt results in the below error.

```
You are not authorized to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account
```

[image]

I used the `Office365 Outlook Connector` in my flow, with action `Send an email (V2)` and, afterwards, i added the `Administrator's account` in the "From" field, of the action.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the connection in "Send an email (V2)" is of **User1**. And you need to send email on behalf of Admin Account i.e. **AdminUser1**.

**User1** should should have Send on behalf permission on **AdminUser1** Mailbox.

Steps :

1. Go To exchange Admin Center
2. Click on MailBoxes from the left navigation
3. Click on the **AdminUser1** (it will open **AdminUser1** Mailbox settings in callout menu)
4. click on Manage mailbox delegation (under Mailbox Permissions) (refer below image)
   [image]
5. Click on **Edit**  for the send on behalf permissions
6. Add the **User1** here.
7. Once these settings are configured, **User1** will have permissions to send email on behalf of **AdminUser**

Comment: So each new user should be added to delegation again?